# Looping process by using AWK bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I try to do like the output below by using AWK but still have problem in looping process.

```
# # # r e a d   //'r' is the focus character, before 'r' is null & assign with "#" and after 'r' are e,a,d
# # r e a d #   //'e' is the focus character, before 'e' is r and after 'e' are a,d
# r e a d # #   //'a' is the focus character, before 'a' are r,e and after 'a' are d,i,n,g
r e a d # # #   //'d' is the focus character, before 'd' are r,e,a and after 'd' is null and sign with "#"
```

Here is the way I'm coding:

```
awk '
{
    for (i=1; i<=length($1); i++) print "#"
        for (j=1; j<=1; j++) print substr ($1, j, 1)
        print ""
} ' file
```

But only first filed is appear and how to make the next field looping? Please guide me

```
#
#
#
r
```

Comment: `for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)`

Comment: [edit] your question to show us the input associated with the expected output you posted.

Comment: the indentation does not match the syntax: the first `for` only executes the first `print`, the second `for` only executes the second `print`. You need to add braces ( `for( ..) { ... } ` to define the loop bodies.

Comment: Thanks guys for your guide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my wild guess is you're trying something like this

```
$ echo "hello" | awk '{word=$1; len=length(word); tlen=2*len-1;
                       for(i=1;i< len;i++) a[i]="#"; 
                       for(j=1;j<=len;j++) a[i+j-1]=substr(word,j,1);
                       for(r=1;r<=len;r++) 
                         {for(i=1;i<=tlen;i++) printf "%s ", a[(i+r-2)%tlen+1];
                          print "" }}'

# # # # h e l l o
# # # h e l l o #
# # h e l l o # #
# h e l l o # # #
h e l l o # # # #
```

I think it can be simplified little more but not sure it's correct or not.